# Create posts by any logged in users

Tags: posts, front-end, wp-insert-post

I want to allow logged-in any users to create posts. For this purpose I created a form

```
<form>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="post_title" placeholder="Title">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="post_content" rows="10" placeholder="Content should go here..."></textarea>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit your post</button>

</form>
```

I was following **WP_INSERT_POST** but I am confused about the hook and finally I hooked it in **ADMIN_INIT** (just from guesses) and here the code in *functions.php*

```
function test_insert_post_function() {
    $postarr = array(
        'post_title'    => $_POST['post_title'],
        'post_content'  => $_POST['post_content'],
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => get_the_author_meta('ID'),
        'post_category' => array(1)
    );
    wp_insert_post( $postarr );
}
add_action('admin_init', 'test_insert_post_function');
```

Now I am not finding a way to make a relation between the **submit-button & this Function**

Here is the theme files: https://bitbucket.org/shihab0915/twentyfifteen-child/src

And here is the temporary live URL: https://nullified-nuts.000webhostapp.com/

I found few similar questions here but those were asked & answered 6/7 years ago.

So how can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just letting the authenticated users add posts using the editor in wp-admin?

Comment: Yes, I want them to post via front-end form.

Comment: Ok, the issue is you're trying to hook your function to the admin area when instead you need to POST the post details directly to your script. Remove your `admin_init` hook and instead set the form action to the URL of your PHP plugin file. Then, in the plugin, check for the required POST parameters and use `wp_insert_post()`.

Comment: Sorry, I am not using any plugin. Just created a child-theme of twentyfifteen.

Comment: I would note that the code here will create a brand new post on every single request to the admin area, that is the literal interpretation of what your code does. There's no "when the user submits the form" if statement, and none of the code runs on the frontend. I would start off by implementing a very, very basic form to get to grips with how frontend form handling is supposed to work, e.g. something that just says "Success!" when you submit the form, **then** introduce the `wp_insert_post` etc

Comment: Also `get_the_author_meta` does not refer to the logged in user, but to the author of the current post, so your author will always be the same as the user that created the page the form is located on

Comment: Ok I should use the function get_the_author_meta() to display meta information in front-end but why is the user unable to create a post?

Comment: Am I missing any required action, method, something else?